# Why websocket connection closes after few seconds

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ssl, websocket, haproxy

Well i've been trying to figure out this issue for a while now, but with no results. So we have an aws ec2 instance behind the aws load balancer and an aws free ssl assigned to the load balancer. In our ec2 instance we have an apache web server listening or port 1338 and a websocket server (using Ratchet) listening on port 8080. Between we are using HAProxy with this configuration

```
global
    log     127.0.0.1   local0
    maxconn 10000
    user    haproxy
    group   haproxy
    daemon

defaults
        mode                    http
        log                     global
        option                  httplog
        retries                 3
        backlog                 10000
        timeout client          30s
        timeout connect         30s
        timeout server          30s
        timeout tunnel          3600s
        timeout http-keep-alive 1s
        timeout http-request    15s

frontend public
        bind            *:80
        acl             is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
        use_backend     ws if is_websocket #is_websocket_server
        default_backend www

backend ws
    option forwardfor # This sets X-Forwarded-For
        timeout queue 5000
        timeout server 5000
        timeout connect 5000
        server  ws1     127.0.0.1:8080

backend www
    timeout server  30s
        server  www1    127.0.0.1:1338
```

So everything seems to be working, except for the web socket server. When I try to connect, the connection is successful, but after about 50-60 seconds, the connection is closed as if the user was left the page. And this occurs only when using https. The issue is, that in our httpd.conf we have a mod_rewrite which redirects all http connections to https.

Another issue is, that we have websocket php client script, which we use to connect to the websocket server so we could send notifications from php scripts, but that client can't connect to the server when I'm using the host 127.0.0.1 and the port 8080. When testing locally without ssl and haproxy, everything is working great. I just can't figure out where the problem is. Is it my HAProxy configuration or I need to change something in the aws loadbalancer?

**Edit**
So these are the logs from the haproxy. I just noticed another thing. I keep sending messages to the socket server, the client doesn't get disconnected, so if keep sending dummy messages to the server after every 30 seconds, everything seems to working correctly, but I still can't understand why this issue is only when using HTTPS

```
    Oct 26 16:49:31 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.51.17:18222 [26/Oct/2016:16:49:31.913] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:49:35 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.16.211:6536 [26/Oct/2016:16:49:35.312] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:49:41 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.51.17:18227 [26/Oct/2016:16:49:41.913] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:49:42 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.18.111:22978 [26/Oct/2016:16:49:42.769] public www/www1 0/0/0/126/126 302 1040 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Oct 26 16:49:45 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.16.211:6537 [26/Oct/2016:16:49:45.312] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:49:46 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.62.174:22616 [26/Oct/2016:16:49:46.025] public www/www1 0/0/0/120/120 302 1038 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Oct 26 16:49:51 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.51.17:18230 [26/Oct/2016:16:49:51.913] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:49:55 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.16.211:6540 [26/Oct/2016:16:49:55.311] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:50:01 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.51.17:18236 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:01.913] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:50:05 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.16.211:6545 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:05.312] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:50:11 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.51.17:18240 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:11.913] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:50:12 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.18.111:22992 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:12.791] public www/www1 0/0/0/124/124 302 1038 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Oct 26 16:50:15 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.16.211:6548 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:15.312] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:50:16 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.62.174:22626 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:16.056] public www/www1 0/0/0/120/120 302 1034 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Oct 26 16:50:21 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.51.17:18241 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:21.913] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:50:25 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.16.211:6551 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:25.311] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:50:25 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.18.111:22952 [26/Oct/2016:16:49:23.912] public ws/ws1 750/0/0/65/61448 101 314 - - ---- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /socket/ HTTP/1.1"
Oct 26 16:50:31 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.51.17:18244 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:31.913] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:50:35 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.16.211:6556 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:35.312] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:50:41 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.51.17:18246 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:41.913] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:50:42 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.18.111:22998 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:42.814] public www/www1 0/0/0/154/154 302 1034 - - ---- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Oct 26 16:50:45 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.16.211:6557 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:45.312] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:50:46 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.62.174:22632 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:46.087] public www/www1 0/0/0/132/133 302 1034 - - ---- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Oct 26 16:50:51 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.51.17:18252 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:51.914] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
Oct 26 16:50:55 localhost haproxy[7831]: 172.31.16.211:6560 [26/Oct/2016:16:50:55.312] public public/<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - CR-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "<BADREQ>"
```

Comment: Websockets generally do not work well across load balancers. YOu may have to give the websockets a more direct path to the EC2 instance while handling everything else through the load balancer.

Comment: What does the HAProxy log show for these closed websocket connections?  An example from the log will probably help pinpoint the issue, particularly if the session state at disconnect flags are not showing the usual `----` that shows for successful requests.

Comment: Check the idle time out set for tcp connections in load balancer. In our case the socket connection was disconnected by load balance after 1 minute, so we have to increase the time or reconnect from client side.

Comment: @ar4ix8 Do you get any solution on this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to basically configure the timeout for tunnel, since websockets create a tunnel so on your configuration you just need to add:

```
timeout tunnel 2m
timeout client-fin 1s
```

Documentation on haproxy: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4-timeout%20tunnel

The timeout client-fin although not mandatory, seems to be important as described on their documentation:

> Since this timeout is usually used in conjunction with long-lived connections,
> it usually is a good idea to also set "timeout client-fin" to handle the
> situation where a client suddenly disappears from the net and does not
> acknowledge a close, or sends a shutdown and does not acknowledge pending
> data anymore. This can happen in lossy networks where firewalls are present,
> and is detected by the presence of large amounts of sessions in a FIN_WAIT
> state.

PS: I know it's an old answer but I just had this problem and this was the first result.